# Convert matrix to vector by a column to be one

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] I1   I1   I1   I1   I2   I2   I2   I3   I3   I4
[2,] I2   I3   I4   I5   I3   I4   I5   I4   I5   I5
```

How can I make each column to be one vector, then make one vector for all?

```
[1]  I1,I2 I1,I3 I1,I4 I1,I5 I2,I3 I2,I4 I2,I5 I3,I4 I3,I5 I4,I5
```

I have try this, but the result is not what i want...

```
sapply(b,function(i) paste(b[,i],collapse=","))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed sapply use.

```
> b <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 2, ncol = 10)

> sapply(1:ncol(b), function(i) paste(b[,i],collapse=","))
 [1] "1,2"   "3,4"   "5,6"   "7,8"   "9,10"  "11,12" "13,14" "15,16"
 [9] "17,18" "19,20"
```

Comment: Closely what i want...

but, what i need is...
[1] 1,2    3,4    5,6

Comment: You can only get [1] "1,2" "3,4" "5,6"

Comment: @MirantiVerdianaDewi so`unlist(strsplit(sapply(1:ncol(b), function(i) paste(b[,i],collapse=",")), ','))` then?

Answer (score 1):

It would be faster (assuming you have more columns than rows) and less typing to use `paste0` to combine the two rows of your matrix, sticking a comma in between:

```
paste0(mat[1,], ",", mat[2,])
# [1] "I1,I2" "I1,I3" "I1,I4" "I1,I5" "I2,I3" "I2,I4" "I2,I5" "I3,I4" "I3,I5" "I4,I5"
```

Data:

```
mat <- combn(paste0("I", 1:5), 2)
```

Comment: or `paste(c(mat),collapse=",")`